# Region Proposal Network Loss Function Faster R-CNN in Python

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensor, valueerror, faster-rcnn

I have been trying to create a custom loss for the region proposal network for Faster R-CNN.

Here is my loss class:

```
class RPN_Loss(tf.keras.losses.Loss):
  def L_cls(self,objectness_pred,objectness_true):
     cls_loss = -objectness_true * math.log(objectness_pred) - (1 - objectness_true) * math.log(1 - objectness_pred)
     return cls_loss

  def L1_smooth(self,d):
    if abs(d) < 1:
       return 0.5 * abs(d)**2
    else:
       return abs(d) - 0.5

  def bb_loss(self,difference):
    loss = 0
    for d in difference:
      loss += self.L1_smooth(d)
    return loss

  def call(self, y_true, y_pred):
    # loss = tf.reduce_sum(tf.reduce_mean(tf.math.square(y_pred - y_true), axis=-1))
    # print(loss)
    # return loss
    y_true = y_true
    y_pred = y_pred
    image_width = y_true.shape[1]
    image_height = y_true.shape[2]
    k = int(y_true.shape[3]/6)
    num_anchors = image_width*image_height*k

    y_true = y_true.reshape(-1,num_anchors,6,order='F').tolist()
    y_pred = y_pred.reshape(-1,num_anchors,6,order='F').tolist()

    batch_size = len(y_true)

    mini_batch_size = 256

    l = 1/mini_batch_size * num_anchors

    batch_losses = list()
    for (true_labels, pred_labels) in zip(y_true, y_pred):
        class_loss = 0
        offset_loss = 0

        offset_true = list()
        objectness_true = list()
        for t in true_labels:
          bbox = [t[0],t[1],t[2],t[3]]
          objectness = [t[4],t[5]]
          offset_true.append(bbox)
          objectness_true.append(objectness)

        offset_pred = list()
        objectness_pred = list()
        for p in pred_labels:
          bbox = [p[0],p[1],p[2],p[3]]
          objectness = [p[4],p[5]]
          offset_pred.append(bbox)
          objectness_pred.append(objectness)

        positive_indices = list()
        for i in range(len(objectness_true)):
           if objectness_true[i] == [1,0]:
               positive_indices.append(i)
        random.shuffle(positive_indices)
        positive_indices = positive_indices[:int(mini_batch_size/2)]

        negative_indices = list()
        for i in range(len(objectness_true)):
           if objectness_true[i] == [0,1]:
               negative_indices.append(i)
        random.shuffle(negative_indices)
        negative_indices = negative_indices[:mini_batch_size - len(positive_indices)]

        indices = positive_indices + negative_indices

        for i in indices:
          pred_obj = objectness_pred[i][0]
          if pred_obj == 1:
             pred_obj -= 0.0000001
          elif pred_obj == 0:
             pred_obj += 0.0000001

          class_loss += self.L_cls(pred_obj,objectness_true[i][0])           
          difference = list()

          for j in range(4): 
            difference.append(offset_pred[i][j]-offset_true[i][j])

          if objectness_true[i][0] == 1:
            offset_loss += self.bb_loss(difference)

        batch_losses.append(class_loss * 1/mini_batch_size + offset_loss * l/num_anchors)

    loss = tf.convert_to_tensor(tf.reduce_sum(batch_losses)/batch_size, dtype=tf.float32)
    return loss
```

Here is my network:

```
inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(feature_map_width, feature_map_height, 3), name="img")
conv2d = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=512, kernel_size=3, padding="same", activation="relu",name='conv2d')(inputs)
objectness = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(k*2, 1, padding="same", name='objectness',activation="softmax")(conv2d)
offset = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(k*4, 1, padding="same", name='offset',activation="tanh")(conv2d)
combined_output = tf.keras.layers.Concatenate(axis=-1,name='combined_output')([offset,objectness])
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=combined_output, name="region_proposal_network")   
model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.experimental.SGD(), metrics=['accuracy'], loss=RPN_Loss(),run_eagerly=True)
```

Here is my training function:

```
    region_proposal_network.fit(
        feature_maps_train,
        combined_output_train,
        epochs=EPOCHS,
    )

feature_maps_train = array of shape (num_images, feature_map_width, feature_map_height, 3)
combined_output_train = array of shape (num_images,feature_map_width, feature_map_height, num_scales * num_aspect_ratios * 6)
```

I get this error when I try to train the model:

```
    f"No gradients provided for any variable: {variable}. "
ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable: (['conv2d/kernel:0', 'conv2d/bias:0', 'offset/kernel:0', 'offset/bias:0', 'objectness/kernel:0', 'objectness/bias:0'],). Provided `grads_and_vars` is ((None, <tf.Variable 'conv2d/kernel:0' shape=(3, 3, 3, 512) dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[[[-0.01343286, -0.01888686, -0.00529547, ...,  0.01197131,
          -0.00748096, -0.00775654],
         [ 0.02271027, -0.02306192,  0.00606766, ..., -0.00177762,
          -0.01731667, -0.03264561],
         [-0.00065003,  0.02647229, -0.01462545, ...,  0.00175561,
           0.02300523, -0.01071106]],

        [[-0.00618983, -0.00712612,  0.00361617, ...,  0.02344079,
          -0.00537292, -0.02537042],
         [-0.03058219,  0.00041968, -0.03347861, ...,  0.0030024 ,
          -0.01555372, -0.02688878],
         [-0.02868438, -0.01187303, -0.03045027, ..., -0.02268067,
           0.03000954, -0.0144286 ]],

        [[-0.02428736,  0.02811098, -0.02376178, ..., -0.0172639 ,
          -0.00108058, -0.02649576],
         [-0.00349842,  0.02964124,  0.01673627, ...,  0.01459278,
          -0.00644417, -0.0279831 ],
         [-0.03581808,  0.02333764,  0.01939235, ..., -0.00829913,
          -0.01123484, -0.01777104]]],


       [[[ 0.0172668 , -0.016689  , -0.00180583, ..., -0.01868539,
          -0.01235346, -0.02740838],
         [ 0.01688728,  0.03080691,  0.01591902, ..., -0.01413891,
          -0.03294617,  0.02786894],
         [-0.02019688,  0.02950937,  0.01928679, ...,  0.02820917,
          -0.01408442, -0.003783  ]],

        [[ 0.01653954, -0.02586307,  0.02855083, ..., -0.0062715 ,
           0.01594009, -0.02496744],
         [ 0.02267117, -0.01587306, -0.02237527, ...,  0.02858471,
           0.01492822, -0.02652461],
         [-0.00677406, -0.02429476, -0.00524556, ..., -0.00330915,
           0.02853324,  0.00173617]],

        [[ 0.02884191,  0.02914567,  0.00987437, ..., -0.01267441,
          -0.01683347,  0.02900441],
         [ 0.02470054, -0.02131175, -0.03123331, ..., -0.01215079,
           0.02494902, -0.01577849],
         [ 0.01409565,  0.01137977,  0.0045033 , ..., -0.03225153,
           0.00012057,  0.03081813]]],


       [[[-0.0231121 ,  0.01859267,  0.00276851, ..., -0.03518654,
          -0.03586396,  0.00537533],
         [-0.00138112, -0.02361653,  0.01144928, ...,  0.02670791,
          -0.03242223,  0.02050216],
         [-0.0190783 , -0.03119262,  0.02539565, ..., -0.03127851,
           0.00543788, -0.00361671]],

        [[ 0.01234447,  0.01534006, -0.00166823, ..., -0.00534617,
           0.02577367, -0.02816694],
         [-0.00443446,  0.02510324, -0.02868736, ..., -0.02043434,
          -0.01679378,  0.02112513],
         [ 0.01203599,  0.01304805, -0.01477428, ...,  0.02151761,
          -0.02817072, -0.03022456]],

        [[ 0.03135695,  0.02041331, -0.00501442, ...,  0.01397586,
           0.03061815, -0.00962073],
         [ 0.01448693, -0.02054271,  0.03065778, ..., -0.0267976 ,
          -0.01065332,  0.00280474],
         [ 0.01681296, -0.03517961,  0.02710834, ..., -0.00313658,
           0.01844857,  0.00649454]]]], dtype=float32)>), (None, <tf.Variable 'conv2d/bias:0' shape=(512,) dtype=float32, numpy=
array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0.], dtype=float32)>), (None, <tf.Variable 'offset/kernel:0' shape=(1, 1, 512, 36) dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[[[-0.02795529,  0.01335894, -0.05879723, ..., -0.07994804,
           0.02904692,  0.09039599],
         [ 0.06649321,  0.0053383 , -0.0518861 , ..., -0.03700397,
          -0.05194901,  0.07781617],
         [-0.10043034,  0.0680778 ,  0.0373121 , ...,  0.05795141,
          -0.00371372,  0.04036274],
         ...,
         [ 0.09186777, -0.01523343,  0.09149472, ...,  0.05974815,
          -0.09119453, -0.04514151],
         [-0.01072095, -0.07760822,  0.06508378, ..., -0.03493319,
           0.01899042,  0.04118478],
         [-0.06652716, -0.09482221, -0.02947614, ..., -0.02247784,
           0.05698048, -0.05702591]]]], dtype=float32)>), (None, <tf.Variable 'offset/bias:0' shape=(36,) dtype=float32, numpy=
array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0.], dtype=float32)>), (None, <tf.Variable 'objectness/kernel:0' shape=(1, 1, 512, 18) dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[[[-0.05874455, -0.10592403,  0.04408782, ...,  0.02970312,
           0.0257002 , -0.01416017],
         [-0.06039866,  0.08035433,  0.03082616, ..., -0.09434153,
           0.04138521,  0.06102253],
         [ 0.03285726, -0.10434896, -0.00927083, ..., -0.0504355 ,
          -0.01865506, -0.08308701],
         ...,
         [-0.00373643, -0.00208239, -0.05394292, ...,  0.0197736 ,
           0.04223693, -0.08301237],
         [ 0.08038757,  0.10273536,  0.00914798, ..., -0.09706689,
          -0.05556377,  0.06713001],
         [-0.00322334, -0.02718291, -0.027419  , ...,  0.00462285,
           0.04802493,  0.03685544]]]], dtype=float32)>), (None, <tf.Variable 'objectness/bias:0' shape=(18,) dtype=float32, numpy=
array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0.], dtype=float32)>)).
```

I tried converting my loss from a float to a Tensor, but this did not help.

I also hope that I have properly implemented the Faster R-CNN loss function.

Any help would be much appreciated, as I am new to Tensorflow!

Comment: You have to implement your whole loss using tensorflow operations, not plain python ones or numpy, it will never work as implemented currently.

Comment: That will be quite difficult given that I have to take a sample of positive and negative anchors. Is there a tensor function that would allow me to do that? The positive truth anchors have a label of [1,0] and the negative truth anchors have a label of [0,1].

Comment: Also, how could I create a limited batch size (128 positive boxes and 128 negative boxes)?

Comment: The sampling is not part of the loss, the loss just takes inputs, what I said is that the loss has to be implemented using tensorflow functions, so gradients can be computed.

Comment: How then should I go about implementing the sampling? Does the sampling occur outside of the loss function? If so, where should I implement it?